# Capturar somente um elemento de um array

Tags: php, array

Tenho o seguinte *array*, como eu poderia armazenar em um novo *array* somente o "produto_id" de todas "loja_id"?

```
array(2) { 
      [0]=> array(2) { 
          ["loja_id"]=> string(3) "286" 
               [0]=> array(2) { 
                   ["produto_id"]=> string(4) "7224" ["qtd"]=> int(1) 
                } 
               [1]=> array(2) { 
                   ["produto_id"]=> string(4) "7167" ["qtd"]=> int(1) 
               }
      }
      [1]=> array(2) { 
           ["loja_id"]=> string(3) "133" 
               [0]=> array(2) { 
                    ["produto_id"]=> string(4) "1078" ["qtd"]=> int(1) }
               } 
       }
```

Comment: Faça um var_dump do array e mostre na  pergunta, por favor. A representação atual me parece errada.

Comment: Pronto, alterei minha pergunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode usar `array_map()` para modificar/reorganizar o array de saida e `array_column()` para capturar os dados da chave `produto_id` de uma só vez.

A palavra chave `use` importa a variável `$produtos` para o escopo da função anônima note que ela é alterada por referência (`&`), `array_push()` combinado com o operador `...` adicione cada elemento do array retornado por `array_column()` em `$produtos`

```
$str = '[{"loja_id":"286",  "0":{"produto_id":"7224","qtd":1},  "1":{"produto_id":"7235","qtd":1}},{"loja_id":"133","0":{"produto_id":"1078","qtd":1}}]';

$json = json_decode($str, true);

$produtos = array();
array_map(function($item) use(&$produtos){array_push($produtos, ...array_column($item, 'produto_id')); }, $json);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($produtos);
```

Retorno:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 7224
    [1] => 7235
    [2] => 1078
)
```

Comment: Como que ficaria para extrair apenas os produtos? Por exemplo: [7224, 7235, 1078]

Comment: @DiegoVieira fica algo como `foreach($novo as $itens){
 echo 'loja: '. $itens['id_loja'] .'<br>produtos: <br>';
 foreach($itens['produtos'] as $item){
  echo $item .'<br>';
 }
}`

Comment: @DiegoVieira vc não precisa do `loja_id`? se não da pra mudar o formato no `array_map()` posso editar a resposta.

Comment: Para a função atual não vou precisar não. Ele só está no array original pq vou usar mais pra frente no projeto. OBS: Esse array está em uma session.

Comment: Só preciso dos produto_id para fazer um select no banco.

Comment: @DiegoVieira modifiquei a resposta.

Comment: Ele ta me retornando um array vazio: Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => 
)

Comment: @DiegoVieira vc tem deve usar o array `$produtos` o `$novo` não vai ter nada mesmo.

Comment: Uma coisa que eu esqueci de perguntar. Tu acha que eu montei o array corretamente? Teria alguma forma de montar em que eu possa acessar os elementos apenas com foreach, ou seja, sem precisar usar o array_map?

Comment: @DiegoVieira se tirar o `array_map()` vai precisar de outros 2 ou 3 foreachs e verificar as chaves para dai extrair os valores.

Comment: Eu tinha tentado dessa forma aqui, mas ele nao reconhece o index: foreach($array as $a){
            foreach($a as $produto){
                $p[] = $produto['produto_id'];
            }
        }

Comment: @DiegoVieira se for fazer dessa maneira vc precisa de um `isset()` para checar se a chave existe, como vc tem indices diferentes acontece isso.